# Devise doesn't send mail in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer

I can't seem to get devise to send the confirmation mail in production.  No error in the log, and sendmail works fine.  Here is my production config:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {  
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,  #this is the important stuff!
  :address => "localhost",
  :port    => 25,
  :domain  => 'beautifulidiot.com',
  :openssl_verify_mode  => 'none',
  :perform_deliveries => true
}
```

I've tried changing the delivery method to :smtp, also no luck.  This is Rails 3.2.5.

Thanks for any help,
Kevin

Comment: add  `config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true` and if you wanna try by `smtp` then port should be `587` instead `25`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you set your delivery_method as `:sendmail` but you set settings for `smtp`. To fix your problem do either of the following:

**Option 1**:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
config.action_mailer.send_mail_settings = { ... }
```

**Option 2**:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { ... }
```

It looks like your settings are for `:sendmail` though, so better to try option 1 first.

Answer (score 1):

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port                 => 587,
      :domain               => 'mail.google.com',
      :user_name            => 'lisabrown472@gmail.com',
      :password             => 'XXXX',
      :authentication       => 'plain',
      :enable_starttls_auto => true  
  }
```

and replace the credentials as per your one

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

and don't forget to restart the server